# Can I transfer a Windows XP license to a different PC and upgrade to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a retail version of Windows XP on a PC I no longer use.  I would like to install Windows 7 on a new pc (nothing is on the hard drive).  Can I purchase a Windows 7 upgrade, and install it using the existing Windows XP CD to upgrade from?

Comment: please visit http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7?T1=tab03
for more info about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have an **existing retail XP licence**, then you are fine to install Windows 7 using a retail upgrade licence. The reason being is that a retail licence is not bound to a particular machine, but an OEM licence is.

Please keep in mind that this would not let you upgrade the **install** (You cannot upgrade the install from XP > 7, but you can go from Vista > 7). The Windows 7 installer would notify you of this and it should only let you perform a full install of Windows 7.

All in all, you **are** eligible to use an upgrade version of Windows 7, but you would need to do a full install

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

If you have a retail version of XP, you can buy the Upgrade edition of Windows 7, however you will have to do a full install, the upgrade install is not supported.

[From the purchase page on the Microsoft Store](http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/Microsoft/Windows-7-Professional-Upgrade/?WT.mc_id=WindowsUKSite_BuyPage)

### Running earlier versions?

If you have Windows XP, you can purchase Windows 7 Upgrade versions. But you must back up your files, clean install, and reinstall your applications.
If you’re running Windows 2000, you’ll need to purchase the full product and do a clean install.

Comment: full retail CD, yes. OEM CD? No.

Answer (score 0):

you can buy an upgrade disc alright, but you are not eligible to Windows Anytime Upgrade (at a reduced rate), you'll have to pay the full price. and since you'll have to do a clean installation from scratch anyway, you might as well grab 'the real deal'.