# Is it easy to transfer a Windows 7 license from one machine to another?

Tags: windows-7, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I transfer a Windows 7 license to another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/36386/can-i-transfer-a-windows-7-license-to-another-computer)

Is it easy to transfer a Windows 7 license from one machine to another? 
(Obviously it will only be one machine at a time.)

I am wondering if the license key is use once only.

I intend to upgrade my old PC to Windows 7, then some time in the next 12 months buy a new PC (with Windows 7 installed already), trash my old one and upgrade a laptop with the first copy of Windows 7

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/36386/can-i-transfer-a-windows-7-license-to-another-computer. Also (but not quite) -http://superuser.com/questions/51430/can-i-transfer-a-windows-xp-license-to-a-different-pc-and-upgrade-to-windows-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about an OEM edition of Windows, the licence dies with the machine and it cannot be transferred.

If you are talking about a retail / fully packaged product you simply need to stop using it and remove it from the old machine then install on to the new machine.

There is nothing technical to actually transferring / removing a licence.

Activation should not be a problem, but if it fails, simply ring Microsoft on the free phone number and they will either give you a one off activation code or unblock your existing key. However, as long as this isn't done more than a few times a month, you should not have any problem - activation is really there just to stop the people who install on **MANY** machines.

Comment: "the licence dies with the machine", well put haha, +1.